# Selecting and switching to veryhidden Sheet not working properly

Tags: vba, excel

I have been writing a few macros lately to navigate around sheets / change visibility / import-export data etc. I normally just embed the macros as buttons on the sheets.
Normally this works well, however, I do keep experiencing an issue where with a macro, or a userform I unhide a veryhidden sheet, select it and exit the macro, or form.

I do this though via:

```
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    .visibile = xlsheetvisible
    .activate 
    .Range("A1").select
End With
```

When I then try to manipulate the sheet - e.g. type in a cell, delete data from cell, or insert / delete rows using the GUI rather than doing it via code, the operations happen on the original sheet with the button that called the form or macro. rather than the new one....

Is anyone else experiencing this? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: it should be `.Visible` and not `.visibility`

Comment: Can you explain your question further? What is your specific issue?

Comment: The issue is that while the macro works to unhide the sheet, and select cell A1, when I right click a row for example to insert row, or when I make any edits to the cells, excel performs everything on the original sheet that was active before I called the macro to unhide the veryhidden sheet so that I can edit it. Does that make more sense?

Btw, @ShaiRado, thanks a lot for the edit (couldn't get it to show as code for some reason) - and yes, it is visible - corrected that :)

Comment: This code doesn't `delete data from cell, or insert / delete rows`.  How are we supposed to help you.  Please improve your question by adding the pertinent code.

Comment: @ThomasInzina I don't want to use code to edit / insert / delete. I want to use the code to get to the sheet and then edit it normally, using the excel application, not VBA

Comment: My apologies I just reread the question.  That's just weird.  You can try using [The Excel VBA Code Cleaner](http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/CodeCleaner.htm).  It will rebuild your workbook for you.

Comment: Is there any chance that you have more than one sheet selected when you try your operation?

Comment: I tried the _Excel VBA Code Cleaner_, and it didn't work (nice utility though - thanks for the recommendation)

Comment: No, only one sheet is selected... and proof is that the changes i make do happen, they just happen on the _initial sheet_ and _only the initial sheet_ :). When I select that one, all the changes that i was trying to make are already there... I also tried adding `application.screenupdating = true` before `unload me` but that didn't seem to help either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the Solution!!!

Upon further investigation it seems like this is **only broken in Office 2013**. I tried it on Office 2010 and it worked fine.

The solution is to invoke the `vbModeless` command after `Userform.show` so that would be:
`Userform1.Show vbModeless`

Not perfect, if you want the user to dismiss the Userform before going back to the worksheet, but hey -it's a workaround :)

Let's hope Office 2016 will fix the bug (I'll be upgrading later this month)

Answer (score 1):

Give worksheet object for cells while referring the editing

for ex... **sheets().range().paste**

or activate the sheet which you want to manipulate before your code (which manipulates the sheet)

Comment: Not sure what you mean. **I am not manipulating the sheet with code. I am using code to unhide a very hidden sheet**, so that it can be manually edited. The issue is that even though at the end of the macro the sheet is visible and apparently selected, any manipulation happens on the previously selected sheet...